# Windows Firewall Inbound Rule adding scope failure

Tags: ip-address, azure, windows-firewall

I have a Microsoft Azure web app with outbound IP addresses:

[image: Outbound IP Addresses]

I added these to my Windows Firewall inbound rule:

[image]

But adding these IP addresses causes everything to fail.
Has anyone seen this behavior?

NOTE: If I instead choose "Any IP Address" everything works as expected, but obviously I don't want that...

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you also must add the **Additional Outbound IP Addresses**

[image]

Hope this helps!